# Automatically run ruby script after server load - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file named Cron.rb located in app/lib.

To execute the file I do something like this.

```
Cron.run
```

This executes a method which creates a thread and processes cron jobs that I have programmed into the file.

I want a graceful way of automatically starting this Cron.run function when rails is started in either development or production. I can't use a cron Job to start this file. I want it to start alongside the current instance of ActiveRecord with all the other Models, etc.

Comment: Why don't you add something to `config/initializers` ?  `startup_cron.rb` which contains `Cron.run` ?

Comment: Such an easy solution! This worked, thanks! @SteveTurczyn

Comment: @SteveTurczyn - would you mind posting your comment as an answer, so the question would be flagged as "answered" ... and would stop popping up on my screen ;-) ...?

Comment: @Myst no problem, now done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute code when rails is started, add an initializer.

It just needs the one line you want to execute.

*config/initializers/startup_cron.rb*

```
Cron.run
```